# Bloch waves under space inversion (parity) operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, parity

$\mathcal{I}\psi_{n,k}(r)=\psi_{n,-k}(-r)$ is this the true behaviour of Bloch waves under parity operators, or

is this one the correct behaviour
$\mathcal{I}\psi_{n,k}(r)=\psi_{n,k}(-r)=\psi_{n,-k}(r)$?

Parity defined as, 
 $ \mathcal{I}p\mathcal{I}^{-1}=-p$  and $\mathcal{I}x\mathcal{I}^{-1}=-x$, so I think under parity operator both $k$ and $r$ should change sign.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is that you need the lattice to have inversion symmetry to begin with to get a simple answer, otherwise in principle you might get a sum of bloch waves of different momenta.

Following some Cornell notes [here by F. Rana](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ece407/Lectures/handout_symmetries.pdf) which I'll summarise in case the link dies, and add some extra bits.

So supposing you have a lattice which has symmetry $S$ then this reflects itself in the potential having the same symmetry, $V(Sr)=V(r)$. In the case of inversion we have $V(-r)=V(r)$.

Now the bloch functions solve the schrodinger equation,

$$\left(-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2+V(r)\right)\psi_{n,k}(r)=E_n(k)\psi_{n,k}(r)$$

If we replace $r$ everywhere by $r'=S(r)=-r$ then we have that 
\begin{align}
\left(-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2_{r'}+V(r')\right)\psi_{n,k}(r')=E_n(k)\psi_{n,k}(r')\\
\left(-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2_{r}+V(r)\right)\psi_{n,k}(r')=E_n(k)\psi_{n,k}(r')\\
\end{align}

Which shows that $\psi_{n,k}(r')$ has the same energy eigenvalue as $\psi_{n,k}(r)$. To check what happens with the momentum, we remember that

$$\psi_{n,k}(r+R)=e^{ikR}\psi_{n,k}(r) \quad \text{for } R \text{ a lattice vector} \quad*$$

So translating $\psi_{n,k}(r')$ we have that

$$T_R\psi_{n,k}(-r)=\psi_{n,k}(-(r+R))=\psi_{n,k}(-r-R)$$

but due to the symmetry $-R$ is also a lattice vector so we should have from $*$

$$\psi_{n,k}(-r-R)=e^{ik(-R)}\psi_{n,k}(-r)=e^{i(-k)R}\psi_{n,k}(-r)$$

which is an eigenstate of the translation operator $T_R$ with eigenvalue $e^{i(-k)R}$. So $S\psi_{n,k}$ has the same energy as $\psi_{n,k}$ and an opposite momentum value, which is the same as $\psi_{n,-k}$. The conclusion is then that

$$S\psi_{n,k}(r)=\psi_{n,k}(-r)=\psi_{n,-k}(r)$$

This also suggests a symmetry in the energy $$E(-k)=E(k)$$

---

The other to see that it might be one or the other is to write

$$\langle r | n,k\rangle=\psi_{n,k}(r)$$

On the one hand, using your $\mathcal{I}$ for inversion, we have that $$\psi'(r)=\langle r | \mathcal{I} |n,k\rangle=\langle -r |n,k\rangle=\psi_{n,k}(-r)$$

by acting $\mathcal{I}$ on the left and using $\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{I}^\dagger=\mathcal{I}^{-1}$. On the other hand we can check the crystal momentum of the state after inversion by acting with a translation operator $T_R$ by a lattice vector $R$, writing $T_R=e^{-i\hat{P}R/\hbar}$. We have that $T_R|r\rangle=|r+R\rangle$ or $$\psi_{n,k}(r+R)=\langle r | T_R^\dagger |n,k\rangle=e^{ikR}\psi_{n,k}(r)$$

So we know that $T^\dagger_R|n,k\rangle=e^{ikr}|n,k\rangle$. If we also use that $$T_R\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{I}T_{-R}$$we have that 
\begin{align}
\psi'(r+R)=\langle r | T_R^\dagger\mathcal{I} |n,k\rangle&=\langle r | \mathcal{I}T_{-R}^\dagger |n,k\rangle\\
&=\langle r | \mathcal{I}e^{-ikR} |n,k\rangle\\
&=e^{-ikR}\langle r | \mathcal{I} |n,k\rangle\\
&=e^{i(-k)R}\psi'(r)
\end{align}

So we should have a bloch function of crystal momentum $-k$, and we could call $\psi'$ instead $\psi_{n,-k}(r)$. Then we again assuming the same form of the Hamiltonian and symmetry of the potential we should have that $[H,\mathcal{I}]=0$, to get that the state has the same energy.

---

Another note would be that if you have a (orthogonal) symmetry $S$ of the crystal lattice, then writing the wave function in the other form of bloch's theorem,

$$\psi_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r})=e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}u_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r})$$

We can construct $\psi_{n,S(\vec{k})}$ from $\psi_{n,k}(S^{-1}\vec{r})=\psi_{n,k}(S^{T}\vec{r})$.

\begin{align}
\psi_{n,\vec{k}}(S^{-1}\vec{r})&=e^{i\vec{k}\cdot(S^{-1}\vec{r})}u_{n,\vec{k}}(S^{-1}\vec{r})\\
&=e^{i\vec{k}\cdot(S^{T}\vec{r})}u_{n,\vec{k}}(S^{-1}\vec{r})\\
&=e^{i(S\vec{k})\cdot\vec{r}}u_{n,\vec{k}}(S^{-1}\vec{r})\\
\end{align}
or if we call $u_{n,S(\vec{k})}(r)\equiv u_{n,\vec{k}}(S^{-1}\vec{r})$
$$\psi_{n,S(\vec{k})}(\vec{r})=e^{i(S\vec{k})\cdot\vec{r}}u_{n,S(\vec{k})}(r)$$